# Young-Adult novel, possibly Aquarius?

Tags: young-adult

I've given this the title of Aquarius though I'm not sure that's entirely right.  I read this book when I was in eighth grade (many years ago, during the 80's if you must ask) and the novel, more than likely a Young Adult novel, was about a team that lands on a planet (for some reason I've come to believe the planet was called Aquarius) and they go about checking the place when they start being attacked by spider-like creature.  I don't remember much else, but I've been trying to figure out the title of this book because I'd like to reread it.  Anyone?

Comment: Maybe lookup *Aquarius* then if that's not it come back and [give us the details](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) you know so we can help you find the book.

Comment: I will suggest The Golden Aquarians by Monica Hughes, but that's from 1994...

Comment: That's too late, but thank you.